# PHP simple question: Time issue (custom programming)

Tags: php

I do basic programming, I am a total noob, so please, sorry for asking a very novice question.

I was handled a project, which was working perfectly for years. Suddenly, the equation was off.

The script takes a) a submission date b) a number representing the weeks pending for delivery... then the script outputs the date of delivery, by doing this:

submission date = number of seconds that a weeks has * number of weeks for the delivery)

This is the code:

```
$week = 604800;
$date = strtotime( $subDate );
$newDate = $date + ($delWeek*$week);
//$newDate = date( 'Ymd', $newDate ) . 'T00:00:00';
$newDate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate );
```

BUT, the output in these past days is that, instead of adding weeks, it is adding days...

Per example, if delivery date is 4 weeks, the ouputs adds 4 days instead of 4 weeks.

How come this happened, when the code has not changed? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$delWeek` using `strtotime()`:

```
$date = strtotime($subDate);
$newDate = strtotime("+" . $delWeek . " week", $date);
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate);
```